# Hide table row that contains specified string

Tags: javascript, php

`$row['attended']` can be either 'YES' or 'NO' (strings). I want to hide every row that has 'Attended' as 'NO'. So in pseudo code:

```
if (<tr> contains 'NO') {
    hide that row (<-That's the tricky part to me)
    }
```

My code is on the server side, but I'd be happy to echo out some JavaScript if that's what's necessary.

```
<?php
include 'connect2.php';

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Lisbon');
$today = date('Y-m-d');

$sql="Select * FROM detentions WHERE date = '$today'";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo "<center><table style='width:400px; border:3px solid #444'>
    <tr>
    <th style='background-color:#444'>First</th>
    <th style='background-color:#444'>Last</th>
    <th style='background-color:#444'>Attended</th>
    <th style='background-color:#444'></th>
    </tr>";

         while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['fname'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['lname'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td><center>" . $row['attended'] . "</center></td>";
            echo "<td><button type = 'button' class='unattended button-error pure-button button-xsmall' style='float:right; margin-left:0.2cm' name='" . $row['lname'] . "' id='" . $row['fname'] . "'><b>Unattended</b></button> <button type = 'button' class='editDet2 button-success pure-button button-xsmall' style='float:right' id=" . $row['det_id'] . "><b>Attended</b></button></td>";
            echo "</tr>";

  }
echo "</table>";    
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Do you really need to grab all that from the database, then? Why not just retrieve rows that do not contain 'NO' for `attended`?

Comment: In this case - solve it with php, it is easy, and better, but if you want javascript - it's possible too... provide some example output and setup fiddle, if possible...

Comment: @nevermind I don't know if I'm just being dumb, but I really can't think of how to do with either PHP or JS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace your select statement

`$sql="Select * FROM detentions WHERE date = '$today' AND attended = 'YES' OR attended = ''";`

and remove your if condition.

Comment: I also want that if attended is NULL it will display the result

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to skip the record with $row['attended']="No" in your while statement... An "if ($result.attended=='yes') {add ...} stamement" will do... Though the more efficient and elegant way would be to add a clause on the query statement like:

Select * FROM detentions WHERE date = '$today' and attended='yes'"

As suggested on the previous answer...

Answer (score 1):

You can add a **WHERE clause** unto your **SELECT statement**, which specifies that the **Attended field** should be equal to **no**. This would prevent the unwanted rows from being returned in the first place.

Change your SELECT statement to: 
`SELECT * FROM detentions WHERE date = '$today' AND attended='yes'`